# Rails 2.3.8 application skip controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I am going to ask a little vague question, but here it goes:

I am maintaining a legacy Rails 2.3.8 application. I noticed a weird behavior, first the application was serving `controller_x/action_x` without any errors given that there is an `app/views/controller_x/action_x.rhtml` but there is no definition of `action_x` in `controller_x.rb`. Then, after a while it stopped serving it, I had to create `action_x` empty function in `controller_x.rb` to make it serve the request again.

What could cause that behavior to happen? How can I serve a view of an action while skipping controller?

**Update:**
The error occurring now is:

```
ArgumentError in ControllerXController#action_x

no id given
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using named routes then I don't know why this would happen but in any case, IMO you should have your actions in your controllers even if they're empty. Not for anything more than readable code mind you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the corresponding view file defined (`action_x.rhtml`), you don't have to define the action (it's good practice to define it though, so that others can easier understand what's going on in your project) in order for the view to be served.

What error are you getting? How does your `routes.rb` file look like?

*UPDATE*: That action is expecting a parameter so something like this will work: `http://localhost:3000/controller_x/action_x/1`. Are you sure you only have `map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'` in your routes file?

Comment: I am using the standard route `map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'`, the question is updated to show the error given, thanks

Comment: I believe this default route will catch everything, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#the-default-routes and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#default-routes

Comment: Yes, but if you've defined a more specific route before the default route, and that matches the request URL, the routing engine will use that instead.

Comment: If a previous route handled the request then creating a function in the controller would not have solved the problem. I checked the routes and there is no way that they could match the requested URL. Anyways I created the missing functions in my controller and everything is running fine now, Thanks.